# How to clear spring webflow scope data on exiting the application by simply closing the browser?

Tags: spring, spring-webflow

Details:-

1. Application is developed using Spring webflow 2.1.1 and Spring core framework.
2. Spring webflow acts as a MVC controller for application
3. Application is storing lot of data in spring webflow flowscope variables which is rendered on UI using jsf richfaces.
4. For same application in web.xml session timeout is configured to 120 minutes.

Problem is when browser is closed in between of webflow OR http session is timed out , what happens to data stored in spring webflow flowscope ? It is observed that end state is not called in both scenario. Does that data reside on Java Heap ?

Also as per memory analyser tool, 70% of heap is consumed by webAppServletContext.

Currently application has out of memory issues even after increasing the heap to 3GB.

Answer (score 0):

Spring WebFlow uses HttpSession to store all its contextual information. As long as Servlet Container invalidates/destroys user associated HttpSession, all Spring WebFlow stored variables become destroyed too (well, can be garbage collected).

If you're having memory problems check your Servlet Container settings. Some have mechanisms like a periodic job to clean expired HttpSession, some others clean upon an invalid request, etc...

Anyway, you'll unlikely reach an OutOfMemoryError because of the described mechanisms, as it will show defective Servlet implementation.